# How can I create a histogram in R?

Tags: r

I'm new to working in Unix, so I need help on how to put a histogram together using R in Linux environment?

File:

```
48302   50  0
48303   46  0
48304   45  0
48305   41  15
48306   44  21
48307   74  0
48308   71  0
48309   35  19
48310   66  0
48311   26  42
48312   44  23
48313   69  0
48314   77  0
48315   64  0
48316   60  3
48317   60  2
48318   62  15
48319   71  9
48320   65  13
48321   88  0
48322   4   29
```

I need to create a histogram using the data from the 3rd column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the data in your example into a file, `sample.txt`, you can then invoke R and do the following:

```
$ R
```

Now you're at a R prompt:

```
> d = read.table('sample.txt',col.name=c("col1","col2","col3"))
```

You can confirm that the data was loaded correctly into table `d` using the `dim` command:

```
> dim(d)
[1] 21  3
```

Now you can graph column 3 (`col3`) as we labeled it above when we read it in from the file, like so:

```
> hist(d$col3)
```

Resulting in this plot:

[image: ss of histogram]

#### Running it as a single script

If you want you can create the following `.r` file, call it `hist.r`:

```
d = read.table('sample.txt',col.name=c("col1","col2","col3"))
dim(d)
hist(d$col3)
```

Then run it using R's `Rscript` command like this:

```
$ Rscript hist.r
[1] 21  3
```

This will appear to have done nothing, but it automatically will put a .pdf file in the directory from where you ran it with the contents of the histogram in it.

```
$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml    80 Sep 11 02:35 hist.r
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 12840 Sep 11 02:37 Rplots.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml   302 Sep 11 02:19 sample.txt
```

You can customize this so that instead of a .pdf file you'll get a .png file or what have you.

#### References

- [How to plot a graph in R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-plot-a-graph-in-r/)

Answer (score 0):

The command `hist(...)` will get an histogram for you.

More help about the command from the interactive help from R: `?hist`.